# Python code in atom text editor not executing; terminal opens then closes immediately

Tags: python, terminal, atom-editor, execution

I try to run code and my terminal (command prompt) opens and closes immediately. Perhaps this may be an issue regarding modules or my setup itself?

I could not post the code due to problems within SO's process...

[image]

Comment: Then how can we help you? at least post a screenshot

Comment: Please post the code as text not image.

Comment: Atom doesn't run code out of the box, so it would be helpful to know which package you're using for that.

Comment: I have the same issue.